# Say I have some element $g\in G$ such that $g$ is of infinite order. I want to show that $|g|=|\langle g \rangle|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Say I have some element $g\in G$ such that $g$ is of infinite order. I want to show that $|g|=|\langle g \rangle|$.

I know that if $g$ is of infinite order, then there does not exist any $n$ such that $g^n=1$.

To set up a contradiction, let's suppose there exists $s,t$ such that $g^s=g^t$, if I multiply both sides by $g^{-t}$ I get that $g^{s-t}=g^{t-t}=g^0=1$. This contradicts our original statement of $g$ being of infinite order.

Is this enough to show that $|g|=|\langle g \rangle|$? I have shown that there does not exist any power of $g$ such that it will bring you back to $1$, so can I therefore say that since $\langle g \rangle$ is made of powers of $g$ that it, too, has infinite order?

Edit: $|g|$ is defined as "$n>0$ such that $n$ is the smallest positive integer that gives $g^n=e$ where $e$ is the identity element.

Comment: What is your definition of $|g|$? Is it “$n\gt 0$ if $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $g^n=e$, and $\infty$ otherwise”? or is it something else? Because one definition of $|g|$ is that is the cardinal of $\langle g\rangle$, in which case your question is circular.

Comment: I think I had misread your question...my apologies

Comment: I gave two definitions. You say, “the one you said”. Which of the two? As written, the question is then nonsensical: $|\langle g\rangle|$ is a cardinal, finite or $\aleph_0$, while $|g|$ is either a positive integer or the symbol $\infty$, which is not a cardinal. So you are asking “is the non-cardinal $\infty$ equal to the cardinal $|\langle g\rangle|$?” The answer is “no, they aren’t even the same type of object.” But if you mean, “is $|\langle g\rangle|$ infinite?” Then the answer is “yes”. Prove that $|\langle g\rangle|$ is finite if and only if $|g|$ is finite, in which case they coincide

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That was my initial thought. It's an introductory group theory module, but we define $|g|$ as being the definition you said.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I didn't see your second comment, apologies. We say that $|g|$ is "$n>0$ such that $n$ is the smallest positive integer that gives $g^n=e$"

Comment: And then how do you define it when there is no such $n$? Really, all of this needs to be in the question. Provide enough *context* for people to understand (let alone answer) your question.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This is exactly as much context as I was given, I'm working with just as much as is in my question.

Comment: Your question does not include the definition of $|g|$ (you only put it in the comments after being prompted), so please, don’t claim that you question has all the context. And you haven’t said how you define $|g|$ for infinite order. Right now, your question is, as I noted already, nonsense: you are asking whether an undefined symbol is equal to a cardinal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since $g^s\neq g^t$ for all $s\neq t$, $\langle g\rangle=\{g^k\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ contains an infinite number of elements. Hence, $|g|=\infty=|\langle g\rangle|$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.